# Proof that the sequence $a_{n} = n(-1)^n, n \in \mathbb{N} $ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence is $-1,2,-3,4,-5,...$  I understand that it will oscillate between arbitrarily large positive and negative values as $n \rightarrow \infty $.

How could I formalize that argument?

Comment: You can also note that if you look at $x_{2j}$ and $x_{2j-1}$, the limits of the subsequences differ and hence the sequence must diverge.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan for n odd it tends to $-\infty$ and for n even it tends to $+\infty$... Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  @Sujaan Kunalan suggestion,

There are subsequences

$a_{2j} = 2j(-1)^{2j} = 2j \rightarrow +\infty$ when $n=2j \rightarrow \infty$

and

$a_{2j+1} = (2j+1) \cdot (-1)^{2j+1} = -(2j+1) \rightarrow -\infty$ when $n=2j+1 \rightarrow \infty$

The original sequence cannot converge and this could be concluded in two ways

1 - There are subsequences which tend to different limits when $n$ tends to $\infty$ (that would be sufficient even if the limits where finite);

2 - There is a subsequence which diverges when  $n$ tends to $\infty$

Answer (score 2):

$|a_n-a_{n+1}|=2n+1\geq 1$. So the sequence isn't *Cauchy.*

Then you might also want to show the limit can't be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.